# Elantech touchpad not recognized on Lenovo Ideapad 320

Tags: drivers, touchpad, ideapad, elantech

I have bought a new laptop that of course comes with Windows 10. I installled Ubuntu and my Elantech Touchpad does not work at all and isn't recognized.

- Model: Lenovo Ideapad 320-15ABR
- Ubuntu version: 16.04.1
- Processor AMD A12-9720P RADEON R7, 12 COMPUTE CORES 4C+8G × 4
- Graphics: Gallium 0.4 on AMD CARRIZO (DRM 3.1.0 / 4.4.0-93-generic, LLVM 4.0.0)
- Kernel: 4.4.0-93-generic x86_64

I've installed 16.04.1 instead 16.04.2/3 since AMD drivers don't work on new Ubuntu architecture.

About my touchpad I post all my outputs (Synaptics / Elantech never appear)

```
$ xinput 
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MOSART Semi. Wireless Mouse               id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ EasyCamera                                id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ MOSART Semi. Wireless Mouse
```

---

```
$ cat /proc/bus/input/devices

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=PNP0C0C/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event0 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=10000000000000 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0005 Version=0000
N: Name="Lid Switch"
P: Phys=PNP0C0D/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input1
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event1 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=1

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=LNXPWRBN/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event2 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=10000000000000 0

I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=ab83
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio0/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event3 leds 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=402000000 3803078f800d001 feffffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0006 Version=0000
N: Name="Video Bus"
P: Phys=LNXVIDEO/video/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:01/input/input4
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event4 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=3e000b00000000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=0458 Product=0185 Version=0110
N: Name="MOSART Semi. Wireless Mouse"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:10.0-3/input1
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb2/2-3/2-3:1.1/0003:0458:0185.0002/input/input5
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd mouse0 event5 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=1f
B: KEY=3f0003007f 0 0 483ffff17aff32d bf54444600000000 1f0001 130f938b17c000 677bfad941dfed 9ed68000004400 10000002
B: REL=1c3
B: ABS=1f0100000000
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="Ideapad extra buttons"
P: Phys=ideapad/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.3/PNP0C09:00/VPC2004:00/input/input6
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=rfkill kbd event6 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=13
B: KEY=101400800100c03 400000000300000 0 2
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/sound/card0/input7
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event7 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HD-Audio Generic Mic"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:09.2/sound/card1/input8
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event8 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=10

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HD-Audio Generic Headphone"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:09.2/sound/card1/input9
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event9 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=4

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=174f Product=116a Version=1205
N: Name="EasyCamera"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:12.0-1.2/button
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/input/input10
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event10 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=100000 0 0 0
```

No output for:

```
dmesg | grep SYN
dmesg | grep ELA
dmesg | grep -i touch
```

Output filter pnp:

```
$ dmesg | grep -i pnp
[    0.174035] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS supports [ExtendedConfig ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI]
[    0.174132] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: platform does not support [PCIeHotplug]
[    0.174221] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS now controls [PME AER PCIeCapability]
[    0.174222] acpi PNP0A08:00: FADT indicates ASPM is unsupported, using BIOS configuration
[    0.174232] acpi PNP0A08:00: [Firmware Info]: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-3f] only partially covers this bridge
[    0.206600] pnp: PnP ACPI init
[    0.206772] system 00:00: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
[    0.206974] pnp 00:01: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00 (active)
[    0.207007] pnp 00:02: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PTL0001 PNP0303 (active)
[    0.207145] system 00:03: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
[    0.207213] system 00:04: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c01 (active)
[    0.207703] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 5 devices
[    0.854511] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0
[    0.854567] input: Lid Switch as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input1
[    0.880454] i8042: PNP: PS/2 Controller [PNP0303:KBC0] at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
[    0.880456] i8042: PNP: PS/2 appears to have AUX port disabled, if this is incorrect please boot with i8042.nopnp
[    1.007427] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:01/input/input4
[    7.834864] input: Ideapad extra buttons as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.3/PNP0C09:00/VPC2004:00/input/input6
```

I changed `/etc/deafult/grub`

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash {XXX}" where {XXX} means `i8042.nopnp` and/or `i8042.reset` and/or `i8042.nomux`.
```

I installed:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep -i elan
ii  elantech-0608-dkms 0.2 all elantech-0608 driver in DKMS format.
```

---

```
$ synclient
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
```

`/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` folder didn't exist. I created it and copied `50-synaptics.conf` into it:

```
$ cat 50-synaptics.conf
# Example xorg.conf.d snippet that assigns the touchpad driver
# to all touchpads. See xorg.conf.d(5) for more information on
# InputClass.
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, your distribution will likely overwrite
# it when updating. Copy (and rename) this file into
# /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d first.
# Additional options may be added in the form of
#   Option "OptionName" "value"
#
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad catchall"
        Driver "synaptics"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
# This option is recommend on all Linux systems using evdev, but cannot be
# enabled by default. See the following link for details:
# http://who-t.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-ignore-configuration-errors.html
      MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
      #Manu
      Option "Protocol" "auto-dev"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad ignore duplicates"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchOS "Linux"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/mouse*"
        Option "Ignore" "on"
EndSection

# This option enables the bottom right corner to be a right button on clickpads
# and the right and middle top areas to be right / middle buttons on clickpads
# with a top button area.
# This option is only interpreted by clickpads.
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Default clickpad buttons"
        MatchDriver "synaptics"
        Option "SoftButtonAreas" "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"
        Option "SecondarySoftButtonAreas" "58% 0 0 15% 42% 58% 0 15%"
EndSection

# This option disables software buttons on Apple touchpads.
# This option is only interpreted by clickpads.
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Disable clickpad buttons on Apple touchpads"
        MatchProduct "Apple|bcm5974"
        MatchDriver "synaptics"
        Option "SoftButtonAreas" "0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
EndSection
```

`sudo modprobe -r psmouse` gives no output.

If someone can help me I'll appreciate it. I'm going crazy and warranty don't cover it because the touchpad work well on Windows, even multitouch gestures...